# Hyperlinked pstricks image not working properly with XeLaTeX?

Tags: xetex, hyperref, pstricks

When I compile the following mwe with LaTeX, the clickable surface that leads me to the video is only around the blue image. When I compile with XeLaTeX, clicking anywhere on the page leads me to the video.

How can I make the XeLaTeX output behave like the LaTeX output?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{hyperref}  

\newcommand{\mypic}{
    \psset{unit=0.055}
    \begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
    \pscircle[linewidth=1.2, linecolor=blue](0,0){4.3}
    \rput{-90}(-1.4,2.5){\pspolygon[linearc=0.4, fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=blue, linecolor=blue](0,0)(5,0)(5;60)}
    \end{pspicture}
}

\begin{document}
Some text 
\begin{center}
\href{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mxI9ba6Rexc}{\mypic}
\end{center}
More text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\XeTeXLinkBox{\mypic}` in the link.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, unfortunately that doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Hm. Sorry I misread your question, I thought you had no click area and not too much. I don't know why this happens with pspictures. But you could redraw your picture with tikz (and there you need \XeTeXLinkBox).

Comment: It does indeed work with tikz.

Comment: tikz graphics are inserted already in the tex->xdv step. So there is no problem for xdvipdfmx to determine their sizes. pstricks is handled later. I asked on the texlive list if this can be corrected in xdvipdfmx. If not one could perhaps do something in hyperref.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create it first as image. Needs only `xelatex --shell-escape <file>`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{VerbatimOut}{HR.tex}
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\psset{unit=0.055cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
\pscircle[linewidth=1.2, linecolor=blue](0,0){4.3}
\rput{-90}(-1.4,2.5){\pspolygon*[linearc=0.4,linecolor=blue](0,0)(5,0)(5;60)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
\end{VerbatimOut}

\immediate\write18{xelatex HR}%% 

Some text 
\begin{center}
\href{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mxI9ba6Rexc}{\includegraphics{HR}}
\end{center}    
More text

\end{document}
```